# List of <li>, FadeOut the previous <li> then FadeIn the next <li> on hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover, fadein, fadeout

I'm really confuse with this hover function. So when you mouseOver "list 1", it will DROP/SLIDE the LAST/PREVIOUS "Answer" div that you hover to the RIGHT ---THEN--- FADE IN / SLIDE IN the "Answer" div of "list 1". And so on. Pretty much SLIDE OUT the LAST "answer" div then FADE IN / SLIDE IN the new "answer" div that you hover. Is that make sense ? Truly need your guidance!

So let say this is the list, for example :

```
<ul id="questions">
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
</ul>
```

And let say this is the answer for each Questions from above list :

```
<div id="answer1">Answer 1</div>
<div id="answer2">Answer 2</div>
<div id="answer3">Answer 3</div>
```

Then this is my jQuery code :

```
$("ul#questions li").hover(
    function(){$('#answer1').hide("drop", { direction: "right" }, 800);},
    // this is where i'm lost, is it li:next fadeIn something like that ?? pls help
 );
```

Saw this page : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fadeout-fadein-question but can't make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

I've made a short example of what I think you need: http://jsfiddle.net/gyhYa/

The CSS:

```
div {
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
    display: none;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#questions li').hover(showAnswer, function(){});

function showAnswer() {
    var idx = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var answer = $('#answer' + idx);
    var visible = $('div:visible');
    if (! visible.length) {
        visible = $('div:first');
    }
    visible.fadeOut(function() {
        answer.fadeIn();
    });
}
```

PS: this only works if you hover one element list at a time (ie. until the anim is finished). You'll need to unbind and bind again or use some locking if you need to hover fast over multiple elements.